# Exporting a row of graphics objects broken in MMA8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

How do you make *Mathematica* export a `Row` of graphics. I do not like how `GraphicsRow` handles the graphics, all the aspect ratios and paddings in the figures get messed up. What I like to do is work with each individual figure and then use a simple `Row`,`Column` or `Grid` to combine my figures. Take the following for instance:

```
g1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
      Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> 2.6*72
    ]
```

This creates the Sin plot. What I want to do now is create the following Figure:

```
Fig = Row[{g1, g1, g1}]
```

[image: output]

Then you can use `Export`

```
Export["TestFig.pdf", Fig]
```

This is the pdf I obtain in MMA8:

[image: output]

I just tried this code in MMA7 and it works fine. It had been a while since I wanted to create this type of figures and I never bothered to check if it worked in MMA8. Does any one have a fix for this in MMA8?

The desired output is the one I obtained in MMA7:

[image: desired Output]

Comment: [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html) automatically wraps at a certain line width. If you use `Grid` or `GraphicsRow` or `GraphicsGrid`, etc... then you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is worth bearing in mind that `GraphicsGrid` [assumes equal-width columns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GridsRowsAndColumns.html#796889411) so using `Grid` is sometimes more useful. The same syntax as in belisarius' answer applies. It might be worth exploring the `ImageSize` option to `Export` (see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html?q=Export&lang=en) and [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExportingGraphicsAndSounds.html)).

Also, note the exporting in PDF format uses the [PrintingStyleEnvironment](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PrintingStyleEnvironment.html), which is not how things look on screen. You might get better results if you change your page setup in Printing Settings.

Comment: Good note about the printing enviroment: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]` exports things the way they look on screen. Thank you, `Grid` gives me the same results in MM8 as in MM7.

Answer (score 4):

```
Export["c:\\TestFig.pdf", GraphicsGrid[{{g1, g1, g1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: GraphicsGrid does export the figure in the intended way but notice how there's spacing from one figure to another. Somehow I can never get my graphs to expand the way they should when I use `GraphicsGrid`, `GraphicsRow` or `GraphicsColumn`.  In any case, the comment that simon wrote solves the problem. If I use `Grid` in MM8 then I get the same output as in MM7.

Comment: @jmlopez Good to know you solved the problem. I haven't noticed the difference between your desired output and mine until now. Sorry